# Can write to a file fail in the middle of a flush operation

Tags: c++, csv, fflush

I am writing contents to a csv file ***one line at a time*** and was wondering if write can fail in the middle of a flush operation

**My purpose is to understand the different ways a write to a file can be corrupted**

Assume the following is the structure of the csv file after a successful write to it

```
 1,1001210212
 2,8941321654
 6,845646
 17,564968896
```

Say an error occurs while flushing the 3rd line to file, could it result in the following form

```
 1,1001210212\n       //showing \n just for understanding purpose. Not actually visible as "\n" in the file
 2,8941321654\n 
 6,845
```

Or

```
 1,1001210212\n
 2,8941321654\n
```

or

```
1,1001210212\n
2,8941321654\n
6,845646\n              //Fails right after writing the line. Not sure if such an error is even possible
```

or

```
1,1001210212\n
2,8941321654\n
6,845646
```

**My code if needed**

> something.cpp

```
hash_map<int, unsigned long long> tableData;

//assume hash map is populated here

string outFile = "C:\outFile.csv";
FILE *fout = NULL;

if (outFile.length())
{
    fout = fopen(outFile.c_str(), "a");
}   
if (fout != NULL)
{
    for (vector<uint32_t>::iterator keyValue = keys.begin(); 
    keyValue != keys.end(); ++keyValue)
    {
        fprintf(fout,"%d,",*keyValue);
        fprintf(fout,"%lld\n",tableData[*keyValue]); 
        fflush(fout); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing a `'\n'` does not flush the stream.

Comment: Did you try to write it with standard C++ ?

Comment: to print an unsigned long long you should use %lld

Comment: Thank you @RSahu. I was assuming otherwise. Will edit it

Comment: There are very few reasons why `fflush()` might fail so long as your file has been opened properly. The only ones that come to mind are either a disk that is brim-full or a catastrophic power failure.

Comment: wrong edit, you must change the second fprintf

Comment: @Logicrat How about a user terminating the program with a Ctrl+C for example

Comment: On many systems, a Ctrl-C will cause an interrupt of the input stream, but won't cause fflush() to stop writing output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard has the following to say about the `fflush` function:

> If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>    undefined.

Notice the careful wording: the data is *delivered to the host environment*. What the host environment does with it is beyond the scope of the C standard.

The `fflush` function may fail. In this case it returns a nonzero value. What actually happens to the file when a flush operation fails is defined by the operating system, not the C programming language.

C is tightly integrated with POSIX. On a POSIX system, `fflush` is likely to invoke `write`. POSIX says,

> If a write() requests that more bytes be written than there is room for (for example, the process' file size limit or the physical end of a medium), only as many bytes as there is room for shall be written.

In addition, `write` may be interrupted by a signal. So if a process is terminated by a signal during a flush operation, only part of the data might be written.

Thus, on a Unix-like system, you should indeed be prepared for the possibility that `fflush` may leave the file in a truncated state.

If it is critical to never leave the file in such a state, then write updates to a temporary file instead, check that all writes succeed at the language level, check that the flush succeeds, and finally rename it atomically to the actual file you want to update.

If you're running on Windows, I have no idea what kind of guarantee is provided.

Comment: Just to ensure I understood it, the conclusion is that anything could happen if flush fails. Could be any of the above examples or even more (like junk values) and there is no definite pattern or expected behavior (at least in Unix). Also there are cases where fflush might deliver the contents correctly, but OS fails to write to file for unknown reasons.

Comment: @iluvcornflakes As far as I know, there is no way to get junk values in Unix, at least assuming you're writing to a journalled file system and not some strange kind of device.